# Js Grid Pager does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

Js Grid External Pager is not working.

I have tried working with Aspo.net Mvc, Back end is sql server

This is my Pager configuration

```
pageLoading: true,
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 15,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            pagerContainer: "#externalPager",
            //pagerFormat: "current page: {pageIndex} &nbsp;&nbsp; {first} {prev} {pages} {next} {last} &nbsp;&nbsp; total pages: {pageCount}",
            pagePrevText: "<",
            pageNextText: ">",
            pageFirstText: "<<",
            pageLastText: ">>",
            pageNavigatorNextText: "&#8230;",
            pageNavigatorPrevText: "&#8230;",
```

My controller returns

```
controller: {
                    loadData: function (filter) {
                        var d = $j.Deferred();

                        $j.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "User")',
                            data:filter,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (response) {
                                var da = {
                                    data: response.response,
                                    itemsCount: response.response.length
                                }

                                d.resolve(da);
                            }

                        })
                            //.done(function (response) {
                            //console.log("response", response.response.length)
                            //var da = {
                            //    data: response.response,
                            //    itemsCount: response.response.length
                            //}
                            //console.log("da", da)
                            //d.resolve(da);
                        //});

                        return d.promise();
                    }
```

My Dom

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="externalPager" class="external-pager"></div>
```

My Css

```
<style>
    .external-pager {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

        .external-pager .jsgrid-pager-current-page {
            background: #c4e2ff;
            color: #fff;
        }
</style>
```

The pager does not load. I am using the external pager. I have used exactly as same as the sample given. But the pager does not seem to load. Am I missing out on something. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to lead at least one "full" page? If there isn't more than one page, you won't get a page. Also, if you don't return the total quantity of results, it also won't know to add a pager.

You have to return the data in the following format for the pager to work correctly with the data loading correctly.

```
{ 
  data: [{your list here}],
  itemsCount: {int}
}
```

It's barely in the documentation, as it's inline and not very obvious. (Bolding mine.)

> loadData is a function returning an array of data or jQuery promise that will be resolved with an array of data (when pageLoading is true instead of object the structure **{ data: [items], itemsCount: [total items count] }** should be returned). Accepts filter parameter including current filter options and paging parameters when

http://js-grid.com/docs/#controller

Answer (score 0):

add new div with ID in my case I had used nbrdeclar it's will work

```js
success: function (response) {
                $("#nbrdeclar").text("Nombre de déclarations :"+response.length);
            }
```